# WPF textblock animation

Tags: wpf, textblock, wpf-animation

How can I achieve **[THIS](https://k-w.tinytake.com/sf/ODQ1OTYzXzM2ODU5ODE)** type of animation? I'm very new to WPF.
I tried with `DoubleAnimation` in WPF but not achieved the target.

Animation should be happen when I update the score like in video it's happening when score is updating from 17 to 23.

Comment: I can't see the link you've posted : This website is under heavy load :-) I'll try later!

Comment: I see the animation. It's difficult to write XAML for you here. Basically you need two DoubleAnimation: one to control the opacity of the TextBlock, and another one to control the translation.

Comment: thanks!  Igor Damiani. But honestly I don't know how to write this :) still I'll try. If you can do more help then plz help me. FYI I'm using VS 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.AnimWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="AnimWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointsNew" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointsOld" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointsNew" From="0 -32 0 0" To="0 0 0 0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointsOld" To="0 32 0 0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid>
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.0" x:Name="PointsNew">
        <TextBlock Text="23" FontSize="96" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Border>
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="1.0" x:Name="PointsOld">
        <TextBlock Text="17" FontSize="96" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Border>
</Grid></Window>
```

Try to play with margin, duration, and so on! :-)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: Ohh man you are awesome! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Thank you, Thank you, Thank you (y)